# Which streams are use for file input/output In C

Tags: c, file-io, stream

I have learn about Console or Terminal input output, where standard streams (`stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr`) use for transmission of data from source to destination.
I want to know that which streams are use for transmission of data from File to Program or from Program to File ?

I am also confused, is `FILE pointer` a type of stream? Because it helps in transmission of data from program to file as well as file to program.

And what are the differences between standard streams and binary/text stream ?

Comment: Check `fopen` .... https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html

Comment: The type of `stdin` etc is `FILE *`. They're all streams. *stream* is an abstraction that simplifies access to console, keyboard, files, pipes, network, printer, memory, ..., ... **A stream is a series of data elements which can be accessed in a serial fashion.**

Comment: @pmg: means standard streams are not only used for terminal Input Output. They can also be used for file input output and others.